# WSO2 ESB dblookup mediator how to call stored procedure with return value?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

When I call stored procedure in DBLookup mediator,
how to get the return value of procedure.

Please show me the sample, thanks.

Comment: have you seen <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326746/how-to-call-an-oracle-procedure-w-out-parameter-in-wso2esb>. Maybe it can help.

Comment: Thank your reply,
DSS I had use. But I have some reason must to use dblookup.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following docs. [1] Contains the introduction to the mediator while [2] points to some samples. I think those samples will provide you the answer.

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB470/DBLookup+Mediator

[2] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=26838877

Comment: Thanks your reply,
The examples you supplied, have no return parameter of procedure.